# Adobe Coldfusion mx7 download

Tags: coldfusion

Where can I find Coldfusion mx 7 download? THis is a bit old but we have a requirements for this software.

Maybe you have Coldfusion mx 7 you can share?

Answer (score 0):

There is a repository of old ColdFusion (and even some Cold Fusion) installs here: [CFML Server - A Different type of ColdFusion Repo - ColdFusion Installs](http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/cfml-server-a-different-type-of-coldfusion-repo-coldfusion-installs).

Obviously these are just the installers: you will still need a *license* to use them other than for development.

Comment: I can just click on a file (eg: coldfusion-702-win.exe) and then the download button. And it downloads; I've just downloaded it. If you can't do that, I guess you need to take it up with copy.com: I have nothing to do with them, and I can have no influence over either them or whatever it might be at your end preventing it from working for you.

Comment: Although your link leads to http://www.gpickin.com/cfrepo/, might be the better link? I accepted the answer. Thanks

Comment: I wanted to specifically lead you to Gavin's narrative first. I figured you'd be able to follow the links form there, once you read what he had to say about this service he's providing for the community.

Comment: Awesome! I will Read Gavin's narrative.